# nginx + gunicorn 502 bad gateway

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django project on VPS server via nginx and gunicorn, but I got an nginx error '502 bad gateway' when I try to open my page `rollservice-rostov.ru`

Something is wrong with my Nginx configuration, but I can't figure out what it is.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rollservice.conf:**

```
upstream rollservice-rostov.ru {
    server 127.0.0.1:8010 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.rollservice-rostov.ru;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://rollservice-rostov.ru/$1 permanent;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /home/django/logs/rollservice/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/django/logs/rollservice/nginx.error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/django/projects/rollservice/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://rollservice-rostov.ru;
            break;
        }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/django/projects/rollservice/templates/;
    }
}
```

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/rollservice.conf:**

```
[program:rollservice]
command=/home/django/projects/rollservice/run/run.sh
directory=/home/django/projects/rollservice
user=django
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/django/logs/rollservice/gunicorn_errors.log
stdout_logfile=/home/django/logs/rollservice/gunicorn_access.log
```

**/home/django/projects/rollservice/run/run.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="rollservice"
SRCDIR=rollservice
HOMEDIR=/home/django

PROJECTDIR=${HOMEDIR}/projects/${NAME}
VIRTUALENV=${HOMEDIR}/.envs/${NAME}
SOCKFILE=${HOMEDIR}/tmp/${NAME}.sock

USER=django
GROUP=django
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS=rollservice.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=rollservice.wsgi

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $PROJECTDIR
source ${VIRTUALENV}/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS
export PYTHONPATH=$PROJECTDIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ${VIRTUALENV}/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=127.0.0.1:8010 \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=$HOMEDIR/logs/
```

Although, my page opens successfully via

```
lynx http://127.0.0.1:8010
```

This is last error logs:

```
 rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:18:34 [error] 11425#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:29:02 [error] 11423#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.148.203.206, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /ccs.php?input HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/ccs.php?input", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:29:02 [error] 11423#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.148.203.206, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /modules/404.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/modules/404.php", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:33:10 [error] 11905#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:33:12 [error] 11905#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.105.68.10, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /ccs.php?input HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/ccs.php?input", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
[vps]rollservice> sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
2014/10/12 23:13:27 [error] 11106#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:16:46 [error] 11295#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:18:34 [error] 11425#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:29:02 [error] 11423#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.148.203.206, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /ccs.php?input HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/ccs.php?input", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:29:02 [error] 11423#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.148.203.206, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /modules/404.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/modules/404.php", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:33:10 [error] 11905#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:33:12 [error] 11905#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 141.105.68.10, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /ccs.php?input HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/ccs.php?input", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"
2014/10/12 23:35:22 [error] 11905#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.72.37.129, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "185.20.226.216"
2014/10/12 23:35:22 [error] 11905#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.72.37.129, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/favicon.ico", host: "185.20.226.216"
2014/10/12 23:35:22 [error] 11905#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 93.72.37.129, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/favicon.ico", host: "185.20.226.216"
```

Comment: Try add `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;` to `location /` block in nginx conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be with the `proxy_pass` is passing to a FQDN due to the naming of your up stream.

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://rollservice-rostov.ru;
    break;
}
```

It is passing it straight to that. Change the name of the upstream and you should be okay.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

i think it's Django configuration related:
if you have set DEBUG to False , ALLOWED_HOSTS is used

To allow any domain name

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
```

To allow only your domain name

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rollservice-rostov.ru',]
```

Config file settings.py may look :

```
...
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rollservice-rostov.ru',]
...
```

To include subdomains , add "." at start

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.rollservice-rostov.ru',]
```

Also , in Django 1.7 and more

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
   '.rollservice-rostov.ru',  # Allow domain and subdomains
   '.rollservice-rostov.ru.',  # Also allow FQDN and subdomains
]
```

Check Django docs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: When `ALLOWED_HOSTS` are not configured, response is not a 502.
502 error is given when something is wrong while sending requests from nginx to django, for example django process does not exists or not properly configured to "speak" with nginx

Comment: I'm using uwsgi in production, but author's question is about gunicorn :)

Comment: Sorry, i know that, can you paste log files content , did you check them?

Comment: Thank you for tip, unfortunately the error hasn't gone. Can you suggest how i can find nginx error log? error_log /home/django/logs/rollservice/nginx.error.log  is empty

Comment: Usually it is located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: 2014/10/12 22:25:16 [error] 8037#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"

Comment: Try add `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;` to `location /` block in nginx conf. Currently nginx is not configured to listen port or socket

Comment: the error stays after nginx restart. I used this article for configuration: http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: try to follow this tutorial. There described main configuration you need: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn
The problem is because something is wrong in nginx, you need to listen port or socket.

Comment: Try to use the short and clean nginx config in the link coldmind just posted and try to edit second line to server 127.0.0.1:8010       max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;

Comment: ok. This is my new nginx config: 

server {
        server_name rollservice-rostov.ru;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
            alias /home/django/projects/rollservice/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }

it works nice with lynx 127.0.0.1:8010

Comment: but with lynx rollservice-rostov.ru - it prints the same error: 2014/10/12 23:18:34 [error] 11425#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.20.226.216, server: rollservice-rostov.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://185.20.226.216:81/", host: "rollservice-rostov.ru"

Comment: yes, it's with http, stackoverflow just hide it automaticaly

Comment: Try to change your `proxy_pass` from `http://127.0.0.1:8010` to `http://{your server's address}:8010`

Comment: Don't know. sudo netstat -tapen | grep ":81" is empty

Comment: changing proxy_pass didn't help

Comment: One clue...may be this is the point: when i run my page via gunicorn its loaded without static files. May be nginx can't reach static and throws 502 error...

Comment: I advice you to run on an unix socket to test, i see that you configured the path  in the **run.sh** but you don't use it, in nginx conf change server line to  `server unix:/home/django/tmp/rollservice.sock;`   and modify your sh file changing  `--bind=unix:SOCKFILE`      also try to add a superior **http {  } block** to your nginx config like this one [link](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#nginx-configuration)

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this, but error stays the same. Thank you guys for helping, I'll keep trying